# Mongodb adding a new field in an existing document, with specific position

Tags: python, mongodb

I am facing this issue where I need to insert a new field in an existing document at a specific position.

Sample document: {
"name": "user",
"age" : "21",
"designation": "Developer"
}
So the above one is the sample document,what I want is to add "university" : "ASU" under key  "age" is this possible?

Comment: Get this doc as a dictionary and then you can simply do that using `doc_to_dict['university']='ASU'`

Comment: I can use $set to add a new key. My specific problem is to add a new key at a specific index, the new field should be under age.

Comment: Why would you do that? Also it will not at all affect your data structure.

Comment: Yes I understand. We are following a specific order, in our database around 30 documents didn't contain this key. Its easy to add a new key, but position matters here. Thanks

Comment: Looking for different workaround to update this field in db.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, first take the document as a `dict`, then we will determine the index of `age` and then we will do some indexing, look below:

```py
>>> dic = { "name": "user", "age" : "21", "designation": "Developer" }
>>> dic['university'] = 'ASU'
>>> dic
{'name': 'user', 'age': '21', 'designation': 'Developer', 'university': 'ASU'}
```

Added the university field, now we will do some exchanging by using `dic.items()`.

```py
>>> i = list(dic.items())
>>> i
[('name', 'user'), ('age', '21'), ('designation', 'Developer'), ('university', 'ASU')]
#now we will acquire index of 'age' field
>>> index = [j for j in range(len(i)) if 'age' in i[j]][0] 
#it will return list of single val from which we will index the val for simplicity using [0]
>>> index
1
#insert the last element ('university') below the age field, so we need to increment the index
>>> i.insert(index+1,i[-1])
# then we will create dictionary by removing the last element which is already inserted below age
>>> dict(i[:-1])
{'name': 'user', 'age': '21', 'university': 'ASU', 'designation': 'Developer'}
```